# Create query with new column concatenate based on CASE/IIF criterias

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have four columns in a table. The table identifies the packaging amounts per box. The four columns are -
ID
PerCase
InnerCarton
PerPack

I want query and create 2 columns ID & Condensed
Column condensed should result in "perCase/InnerCarton/PerPack"
there are many IDs where the InnerCarton is null, so I want the condensed column to show "PerCase/PerPack"

I tried this -

```
SELECT ID,
CAST(IIf([Items_UOM].[InnerCase] Is Not Null
        ,[Items_UOM].[PerCase] & '/' & [Items_UOM].[InnerCase] & '/' & [Items_UOM].[PerPack]
        ,[Items_UOM].[PerCase] & '/' & [Items_UOM].[PerPack]) AS varchar(25))
FROM Items_UOM;
```

I am getting an error message - Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '/' to data type smallint.

Comment: That is because either PerCase and/or PerPack is a smallint. You would need to convert that to a varchar to display it as character data.

Answer (score 0):

[`&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-and-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is the binary and operator, not a string concatenation operator.

If [CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-concat-null-yields-null-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is set you could use [`+`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-concatenation-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to concatenate the values with the slash and [`concat()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to build the overall string. As with `+` the concatenation gets `NULL` if one operand is null the slash gets sort of eliminated for `NULL`s. `concat()` however replaces `NULL`s with an empty string, so the overall result isn't `NULL` if there are `NULL` values.

If the values are integers you need to convert them to a string them prior using them in the `+` as otherwise the `+` is interpreted as an arithmetic plus and results in the engine trying to convert the `'/'` to a number, which of course fails.

```
SELECT id,
       concat(convert(varchar(max), items_uom.innercase) + '/',
              convert(varchar(max), items_uom.percase) + '/',
              convert(varchar(max), items_uom.perpack)
       FROM items_uom;
```

Comment: I am still getting error message -  Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '/' to data type smallint.

Answer (score 0):

You have several things going on here not quite correct. First, to combine strings you use + not &. Second, you have datatype conversion issues because your columns are tinyint and you can't just add characters to add without an explicit conversion. You can also simplify this by using ISNULL or COALESCE instead of IIF and being forced to repeat the logic.

This should work for you.

```
SELECT ID,
    convert(varchar(25), [Items_UOM].[PerCase]) + ISNULL('/' + [Items_UOM].[InnerCase], '') + '/' + convert(varchar(25),  [Items_UOM].[PerPack])
FROM Items_UOM;
```